# Как настроить сохранение настроек биндов? И как сделать бинд клавиши на другую клавишу чтобы эмулировать нажатие?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

Суть в чём? Я пытаюсь написать код C# в VS 2022 на .NET Framework, который будет сохранять все настройки программы в файл JSON, но я не понимаю, что нужно написать внутри файла JSON, нужно ли добавлять файл AppSettings для того, чтобы шлёпнуть код который будет связывать форму настроек и файл JSON?
А почему двойной вопрос? Потому что оно всё связано. Мне нужно сделать двойной бинд а не получается связать это всё. Обычные бинды получаются а связать по схеме клавиша = клавиша + клавиша / системное действие нет.

Вот что у меня в AppSettings если он нужен:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Programm
{
    public class AppSettings
    {
        public List<HotKeysArrange> HotKeysList { get; set; }

        public AppSettings()
        {
            HotKeysList = new List<HotKeysArrange>();
        }

        public void SaveToFile(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented);
                File.WriteAllText(filePath, json);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error saving settings: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        public static AppSettings LoadFromFile(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    string json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppSettings>(json);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error loading settings: {ex.Message}");
            }

            return new AppSettings();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот что в форме настроек биндов:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Programm
{
    public partial class RebinderForm : Form
    {
        public static List<HotKeysArrange> HotkeysLis = new();
        public List<Keys?> KeysListTemp = new();
        public RebinderForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            KeyPreview = true;
        }
        private void RebinderForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.KeyCode);
            if (!KeysListTemp.Contains(e.KeyCode) && HotkeysLis.Any(hotkey => hotkey.OneKey == e.KeyCode))
                KeysListTemp.Add(e.KeyCode);

            if (!KeysListTemp.Contains(e.KeyCode) && HotkeysLis.Any(hotkey => hotkey.TwoKey == e.KeyCode))
                KeysListTemp.Add(e.KeyCode);

            if (!KeysListTemp.Contains(e.KeyCode) && HotkeysLis.Any(hotkey => hotkey.FreeKey == e.KeyCode))
                KeysListTemp.Add(e.KeyCode);

            #region чек нажатых клавиш.
            if (KeysListTemp.Count == 1)
            {
            var temp = HotkeysLis.Where(hotKey => KeysListTemp.Contains(h`введите сюда код`otKey.OneKey) && hotKey.TwoKey == null && hotKey.FreeKey == null).FirstOrDefault();
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    temp.Action();
                    KeysListTemp.Clear();
                }
            }

            if (KeysListTemp.Count == 2)
            {
                var temp = HotkeysLis.Where(hotKey => KeysListTemp.Contains(hotKey.OneKey) && KeysListTemp.Contains(hotKey.TwoKey) && hotKey.FreeKey == null).FirstOrDefault();
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    temp.Action();
                    KeysListTemp.Clear();
                }
            }

            if (KeysListTemp.Count == 3)
            {
                var temp = HotkeysLis.Where(hotKey => KeysListTemp.Contains(hotKey.OneKey) && KeysListTemp.Contains(hotKey.TwoKey) && KeysListTemp.Contains(hotKey.FreeKey)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    temp.Action();
                    KeysListTemp.Clear();
                }
            }
            #endregion
        }

        private void RebinderForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) => KeysListTemp.Clear();

        #region Методы для которых будут задаваться комбинации клавиш
        public void OneMessage() => MessageBox.Show(label1.Text);
        public void TwoMessage() => MessageBox.Show(label2.Text);
        public void FreeMessage() => MessageBox.Show(label3.Text);
        #endregion

        #region передача методов для привязки горячих клавиш.
        private void BindBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingHotkeyForm form = new(OneMessage, BindBox1);
            form.Show();
        }
        private void BindBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingHotkeyForm form = new(TwoMessage, BindBox2);
            form.Show();
        }
        private void BindBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingHotkeyForm form = new(FreeMessage, BindBox3);
            form.Show();
        }
        private void ActionBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingHotkeyForm form = new(OneMessage, ActionBox1);
            form.Show();
        }
        private void ActionBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingHotkeyForm form = new(TwoMessage, ActionBox2);
            form.Show();
        }
        private void ActionBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingHotkeyForm form = new(FreeMessage, ActionBox3);
            form.Show();
        }
        #endregion

        private void CancelRBN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => Close();

        private void SaveRBN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings();
            appSettings.HotKeysList = HotkeysLis;

            string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "sett.json");

            appSettings.SaveToFile(filePath);

            this.Close();
        }

        #region
        private void RebinderForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void BindBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        #endregion
    }

    public class HotKeysArrange
    {
        public Action Action { get; set; }
        public Keys? OneKey { get; set; }
        public Keys? TwoKey { get; set; }
        public Keys? FreeKey { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот по этой причине мне тот пример из вашего предыдущего вопроса и не понравился, ибо в нем тонна лишнего, что вас только запутало. Если взгляните на мой пример реализации, то там вам достаточно сохранить цифру и название команды, ну а сами команды хранить в словаре. При изменении привязок, вы сериализуете полученный список в JSON, а при загрузке формы делаете обратно. В этом коде, по сути, можно сделать аналогично, только `Action` в `HotKeysArrange` замените на простое имя, и также сделаете словарь, который имя преобразует в `Action` и обратно.

Comment: Я просто немного не поняла прошлый ответ, вы могли бы объяснить детальнее?

Comment: Куда еще детальней-то...? Не понимаете что-то, спрашивайте (там).

Comment: А, хорошо, спасибо